# Split single line into multiple line until matches as pecific pattern

Tags: awk

I'm trying to split every single line of data from `c1.txt` into multiple lines and copy it to new file `c2.txt` as shown in Expected result set. But ended up with no difference between `c1.txt` and `c2.txt` and line count for both the files remains same as `two`

**c1.txt**

```
# file: /home/mytest/data # owner: own # group: group-sm user::r-x group::rwx mask::rwx other::--- default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:group:smr:rwx default:group:agm:r-x default:mask::rwx default:other::---
# file: /home/mytest/datasr123 # owner: own # group: group-sm user::r-x group::rwx mask::rwx other::---
```

**Code**

```
awk -v dt="file :" '$0 ~ dt {gsub(dt, "\n"dt)}1' c1.txt > c2.txt
```

**Expected Result**

```
# file: /home/mytest/data 
# owner: own 
# group: group-sm 
user::r-x 
group::rwx 
mask::rwx 
other::--- 
default:user::rwx 
default:group::r-x 
default:group:smr:rwx 
default:group:agm:r-x 
default:mask::rwx 
default:other::---

# file: /home/mytest/datasr123 
# owner: own 
# group: group-sm 
user::r-x 
group::rwx 
mask::rwx 
other::---
```

Comment: I assume your file names like `datasr123` could actually contain spaces, hash signs, etc. right? So what if instead of `datasr123` the file name was `datasr123 # owner: own` - how do you separate the file names from other text on each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`, we can do:

```
sed -E ':j s/ ([^ ]*)$/\n\1/; t j;' infile \
| sed -E ':j /(:|#)$/ { N; s/\n/ /;t j; }'
```

first `sed` command is breaking down the line on every space seen starting from end of line;

second `sed` command joining back those lines that ends with either a `#` or `:`.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` alternative

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ "[#:]$" ) printf $i" "; else  print $i; }' c1.txt
```

And a `sed` variant, though more fragile

```
sed -E "s/([^:#]) ([#a-z])/\1\n\2/g" c1.txt
```

Comment: Unless you have a very specific **need**, don't use printf with input data in the format string as it'll fail when the input data contains printf formatting chars such as `%s`. Do `printf "%s", $i`, not `printf $i`. Also the regexp delimiter is `/` not `"` (that's a string delimiter) so your condition should be `$i ~ /[#:]$/` instead of `$i ~ "[#:]$"` since you don't need/want awk to parse the string first before using it as a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT and assuming that, like your posted sample input, your real input doesn't have blanks, etc. in your file names:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='(#\\s+\\S+:\\s+)?\\S+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i; print ""}' file
# file: /home/mytest/data
# owner: own
# group: group-sm
user::r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:smr:rwx
default:group:agm:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

# file: /home/mytest/datasr123
# owner: own
# group: group-sm
user::r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

Answer (score 0):

worked fine for me

```
for ((i=1;i<=2;i++)); do sed -n ''$i'p' filename |sed "s/#/\n#/g" |sed '/^$/d'| sed "3s/ /\n/3g";echo " "| sed "s/.*/&\n/g"; done
```

output

```
# file: /home/mytest/data 
# owner: own 
# group: group-sm
user::r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:smr:rwx
default:group:agm:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---


# file: /home/mytest/datasr123 
# owner: own 
# group: group-sm
user::r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```